# File upload using requests library from python to AWS S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-requests, boto3

I want to upload a file which got generated using Docker to AWS S3. I tried using Boto3 but unfortunately, Python 3.8 doesn't support boto3. So to overcome this problem I thought to upload using HTTP Requests. I read a few AWS documentation and example but nowhere I found a clear example to simply upload and store the file in s3.

Though I wrote part of the script using documentation but don't know how to proceed further

```
method = 'PUT'
service = 'S3'
host = 's3.amazonaws.com'
region = 'eu-west-1'


def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()


def getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName):
    kDate = sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'), dateStamp)
    kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
    return kSigning


access_key = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
secret_key = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
if access_key is None or secret_key is None:
    print('No access key is available.')
    sys.exit()

t = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
amzdate = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
datestamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d')

canonical_uri = '/'

canonical_headers = 'host:' + host + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + amzdate + '\n'

signed_headers = 'host;x-amz-date'
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks a lot in advance. I am beginner in S3 so don't have much idea.

Comment: Python 3.8 doesn't support boto3 - this is most certainly not the case

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha It doesn't support. I have tried and i got version error

Comment: What exactly is not working? What are the errors you're getting?

Comment: That is for sure some misconfiguration. I work with boto3 on py3.8 daily.

Comment: On running **pipenv install boto3**
I am getting this: 
```
Installing boto3…
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (1ffa85)…
Ignoring idna-ssl: markers 'python_version < "3.7"' don't match your environment
Ignoring importlib-metadata: markers 'python_version < "3.8"' don't match your environment
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 69/69 — 00:00:08
```

Comment: It supports till 3.7, not 3.8

Comment: If multiple people here are saying it works, then believe me we're on to something... It is clearly problem in your environment set up. You use pipenv, which is why it fails: boto3 is installed successfully, but `idna-ssl` package listed in your lock file fails, not boto3. I'd suggest to look into how pipenv works first before relying on it in your work

Comment: ok.. but can you help using HTTP?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/boto3/
clear mention that it supports till 3.7

Comment: Helping you with HTTP is reinventing the wheel. You need to use boto3, but for some reason you insist it doesn't work with py3.8. Except it does:
```
➜ python --version
Python 3.8.2
➜  pip freeze | grep boto
boto3==1.12.28
botocore==1.15.28
```

Comment: It's quite weird. Because when I am installing using pip it's working. But when I am trying with pipenv, i am getting an error in dependencies.

Is there command by which I can fix pipenv issues?